# ¿por que mi codigo JSP genera lineas en blanco?

Tags: jsp

Este es un problema que tengo muy seguido no adjunto codigo por que me pasa en todas las JSP [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner como primera directiva [`<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajm/index.html)? Echa un vistazo otro ejemplo en esta página: [http://www.jcgonzalez.com/jsp-remove-blank-line-directive-source-code](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/jsp-remove-blank-line-directive-source-code).

Comment: No lo había intentado.... Lo hice un funciono perfecto Gracias :D

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara. Si te apetece te cedo la redacción de la respuesta. Mañana si no has contestado la elaboraré yo con enlaces y referencias a la documentación (ahora estoy fuera de casa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es debido a que tras las directivas que estás usando tienen un retorno del carro tras ellas.

Fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<%@include file="..." %>(retorno del carro)
HOLA
```

Generará la siguiente salida:

```
(lo que genere el archivo ...)(retorno del carro)
HOLA
```

Sin embargo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<%@include file="..." %>HOLA
```

Generará:

```
(lo que genere el archivo ...)HOLA
```

Para cambiar este comportamiento en un archivo en particular puedes hacer uso de la directiva `trimDirectiveWhitespaces` de la siguiente manera:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@include file="..." %>(retorno del carro)
HOLA
```

Generando directamente la siguiente salida:

```
(lo que genere el archivo ...)HOLA
```

Puedes comprobar en tiempo de ejecución si dicha directiva está activada o no usando [`JspPropertyGroupDescriptor.getTrimDirectiveWhitespaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/descriptor/JspPropertyGroupDescriptor.html#getTrimDirectiveWhitespaces--).

También puedes [configurarlo a nivel global en `web.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajm/index.html) con un conjunto de [propiedades para grupos](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajg.html) (en este caso todos los archivos `*.jsp`) de la siguiente manera:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```